# 'IXMLHTTPRequest' : base class undefined error when trying to use visual c++ to get a webpage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm following an example with a basic idea of getting a web page async.  The code is here:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <msxml6.h>
#include "comutil.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv)
{ 

HRESULT hr;
CComPtr<IXMLHTTPRequest> request;

hr = request.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_XMLHTTP60);
hr = request->open(
    _bstr_t("GET"),
    _bstr_t("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"),
    _variant_t(VARIANT_FALSE),
    _variant_t(),
    _variant_t());
hr = request->send(_variant_t());

// get status - 200 if succuss
long status;
hr = request->get_status(&status);

}
```

When I try to compile this I get the error:

```
error C2504: 'IXMLHTTPRequest' : base class undefined
```

Is anyone able to see what's wrong with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding `#import "msxml6.dll"` and 
`using namespace MSXML2;` at the top of your C++ file?

Comment: when i do that i get another strange error

    fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'c:\visual studio 2012\projects\httplibtest\httplibtest\debug\msxml6.tlh(13)' was matched

its not a file i included, but looking into it

Comment: The inclusion of the TLH file is actually done as part of the import directive

Comment: I don't have VS 2012 handy (Just 2015) but your code did compile here (although I noticed you should probably put '<' and '>' around 'comutil.h' rather than quotes (That isn't your problem). When you created a VS 2012 project, what type of project did you start with?

Comment: So I found my older copy of VS2012 (Using Windows SDK 8.0) and created a Win32 Console Application. I had to add a #include "stadafx.h" at the top, and your code was missing the Com initialization so I had to add this as the first line of code in main : CoInitialize(nullptr); . Without it you'll get assertions and failure at runtime. Beyond that it compiled without error. The only thing I can think of is you might be using VS2012 Express? (If so it could be something related to that I guess)